# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in Procedure returning result set

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ado.net

I have seen lot of people asking this question but I think I have different case. Nothing is solving my problem so thought of posting it here. I have created procedure in oracle that gives me some table data. Have a look ar procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SMSUADMIN.GetSmsDataByMobileNo
(
MobileNo IN VARCHAR2 := '',
data_c OUT sys_refcursor
)
 IS


BEGIN

    OPEN data_c FOR 
    select v.TOMOBILE,v.SMS_COMPUTED_TEXT SMS_TEXT,v.CREATED_ON 
    sent_date,v.DONE_DATE Received_date,s.SE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION STATUS from 
    TBL_VF_FINAL_STATUS v
    join  SMS_ERROR_MASTER s  on v.ERROR_CODE=s.SE_DECIMAL_VALUE
    join  TBL_SMS_JOB_REQUEST J on j.JOB_REQ_ID  =V.JOB_REQ_ID 
    Where ToMobile = MobileNo;


   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RAISE;
END GetSmsDataByMobileNo;
```

**it works fine** when I run it from `TOAD`. But when I am calling it from `ASP.Net` application, it gives error

stack trace also look frustrating.

```
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterBinding.Bind(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, NativeBuffer parameterBuffer, OracleConnection connection, Boolean& mustRelease, SafeHandle& handleToBind)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at LMS_SMS.DataAccess.DALSms.GetSmsDetails(String mobileNo, String token) in e:\Imad\LEAP_V1.0\DEV\Leap_WCF\LMS_SMS\DataAccess\DALSms.cs:line 42
```

I am calling procedure like this

```
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SMSValueFirstConnectionString"].ToString());
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("GetSmsDataByMobileNo", con);
                System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter param = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter 
                                            {
                                                OracleType = OracleType.VarChar, 
                                                Value = mobileNo, 
                                                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                ParameterName = "MobileNo"      
                                            };

                OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter
                {
                    OracleType = OracleType.Cursor,
                    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                    ParameterName = "data_c"
                };

                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                con.Open();
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);                     

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    smsEntities.Add(new SmsEntity
                    {
                        Delivery_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TOMOBILE"]),
                        Delivery_Status = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["STATUS"]),
                        MobileNo = Convert.ToString(reader["TOMOBILE"]),
                        Remarks = Convert.ToString(reader["SE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION"]),
                        SMS_Text = Convert.ToString(reader["SMS_TEXT"])
                    });
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                con.Close();
```

For sometime I thought problem might be my connection string but if was a problem then it wouldn't have allowed me to open connection, right?

I am getting above exception on `cmd.ExecuteReader()` with or without argument. Please help me tackle this.

Comment: what is the error that C# throws?

Comment: Please try with: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: @PonderStibbons thanks, it worked.

Comment: Also, take the time to switch to ODP.net.  System.Data.OracleClient is depricated, and you will notice many improvements all around

Comment: Thaks for you valuable comment @Hambone. Will consider it.